# SMS are not saving in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, twilio

***Nodejs, MongoDB, Rest API***
I'm using here twilio services for sending the phone otp SMS in MongoDB database, SMS are sending and no errors but otps are not saving in the database. Please help me
how to save the otps in the database.

```
try {
        const { phone } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ phone: phone });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'Phone not found.' 
            })
        }

        const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
        const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
        const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

        client.verify.services.create({friendlyName: `My First Verify Service` })
            .then(service => console.log(service.sid));

        client.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_SERVICES_KEY)
            .verifications
            .create({ to: user.phone, channel: `sms ` })
            .then(verification => {
            console.log(verification.status)
        });

        client.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_SERVICES_KEY)
           .verificationChecks
           .create({to: user.phone, code: `${user.phoneOtp}`})
           .then(verification_check => console.log(verification_check.status));



        await user.save();


        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'OTP sended to your 
             registered phone number.' });
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'OTP not send try 
             again' });
        }
```

Comment: so you are doing await user.save() but when and where is the user.phoneOtp being set ? I don't see that's happening

Comment: You appear to be sending and trying to check the OTP within the same request which won't work because your user won't have the OTP code to check until you have sent it. You also do not need to store an OTP code when you are using Twilio Verify. I would check the documentation for Twilio Verify and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `await user.save();` inside your service through which you are sending the sms. You can put it inside `.then`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, you are not saving the OTP to the database yet.
Right after sending the OTP add
`user.phoneOtp = code;` and  `await user.save();` before proceeding.